# Javascript button that changes properties of html elements using DOM Events

Tags: javascript, html, dom, random, dom-events

I'm trying to make a button that changes the color of the paragraph elements to a random color whenever an user clicks the button. It doesn't seem to work and my text editor (Brackets) are telling me I made 12 mistakes but I don't really sees it. 
This is what I wrote towards the end of my webpage:

```
                    <button id="button1">Color Changer</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src=script.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is script.js:

```
var button1El = document.getElementById("button1");
var paragraphsEl = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var colorChange = function () {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
    for (var i = 0; i < paragraphsEl.length; i += 1) {
        paragraphsEl[i].style.color = rgb(r, g, b);
    }
}
button1El.addEventListener("click", colorChange);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"my text editor (Brackets) are telling me I made 12 mistakes but I don't really sees it"_ What, exactly, is it telling you? My *guess* is that it has something to do with `paragraphsEl.style.color`

Comment: `paragraphsEl ` is going to be an array, an array does not have a style. The elements in the array do

Comment: Inside ESlint: document is not defined. g is already defined. rgb is not defined. b is not defined.

Comment: Inside JSlint: missing 'use strict'. g is already defined. rgb used before it's defined.

Comment: You should really put integers only into `rgb(...)`. Instead of doing `Math.random() * 255` do `Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)` You're also trying to set `style.color` on an array of elements. You need to iterate over the array and set `style.color` on each of them individually. Also, set `style.color` as a string, JS is parsing it as a function so it's looking for a function called `rgb` that doesn't exist.

Comment: You define `g` twice by the way but never `b`

Comment: I edited my code and it's still not working. How do you parse style.color as a string?

Comment: I added an answer with code that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things wrong here, which I listed in a comment above:

- `paragraphsEl` is an array, you can't set `style.color` on an array, you need to iterate over each of the items in the array to set that value
- `style.color` will take a string value, you're trying to call a function called `rgb`, which doesn't exist, pass in a string to make this work
- Use integers in RGB with `Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)

Close, but you seem to be forgetting how a few things work.

Remember that breaking the issue down into pieces and figuring out what data types are being used in certain places will help you avoid a lot of these issues.

```
var button1El = document.getElementById("button1");
var paragraphsElements = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var colorChange = function () {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);

  for(var i = 0; i < paragraphsElements.length; i++) {
    paragraphsElements[i].style.color = 'rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
  }
}
button1El.addEventListener("click", colorChange);
```

Here's a codepen link that demonstrates working code, I had made a couple mistakes because I didn't test it:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdmKVd

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out. I found i declared g two times and I fixed that. I tried your code but now it's giving me 15 problems.

Comment: Did I link the javascript in a wrong way? It keeps on telling me document is not defined.

Comment: You're missing quotes around `src` attribute: `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Comment: No worries. Learn to use debugging tools with Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ you will save yourself a lot of time and effort!

Comment: What editor do you recommend? Brackets keeps on telling me problems that doesn't exist.

Comment: Best editor right now in my opinion is VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/
Note: this is not the same as Visual Studio! Very nice product. Alternatives if you don't like it: Sublime Text (paid, but does have free version, https://www.sublimetext.com/), Atom (free, but has trouble with large files: https://atom.io/). Webstorm: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ I think is also paid but you can get free versions if you're a student, not sure though. All good editors. My favourite by far is VSCode though.